# Microsoft.Speech: Add to Choice from Dictionary

Tags: c#, microsoft-speech-platform

I`ve created a Dictionary with "string, int" . I'm currently trying to get the words in to the choices by doing "ch_Stk.Add".
How can I enter the dictionary in there?

```
Dictionary<string, int> textNumber = new Dictionary<string, int>();
textNumber.Add("eins", 1);
textNumber.Add("zwei", 2);
textNumber.Add("drei", 3);
textNumber.Add("vier", 4);
textNumber.Add("fünf", 5);
textNumber.Add("sechs", 6);

Choices ch_Stck = new Choices();
ch_Stck.Add( . . . .);
GrammarBuilder gb_result = new GrammarBuilder(ch_Stck);
Grammar g_result = new Grammar(gb_result);
return g_result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed it:

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in textNumber)
        {
            ch_Stck.Add(pair.Key.ToString());
        }
```